# Serialization on an object comes out with null fields

Tags: java, serialization

For Reference: I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/danshannon/javastravav3api

For an API OAuth token, the library has no function to store the token perpetually. I tried to just make a class that extends Token and makes it implement Serialization to have perpetual tokens, but whenever I read the token all the fields are null. I checked to make sure the fields are not null right before writing the objects.

```
public class SerialToken extends Token implements Serializable
{
    public SerialToken() {
    }

    public SerialToken(TokenResponse tokenResponse, AuthorisationScope... scopes) {
        super(tokenResponse, scopes);
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // write your code here
        File f = new File("lastToken.txt");
        SerialToken token;
        if (!f.exists()) {
            AuthorisationAPI auth = API.authorisationInstance();
            TokenResponse response = auth.tokenExchange(/*credentials*/);
            token = new SerialToken(response);
            //System.out.println(token.getAthlete().getCity()); used to double check object isnt null going in (which it isnt)
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(token);
        }
        else
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            token = (SerialToken) ois.readObject();
        }

        System.out.println(token.getAthlete().getCity());
      
    }
}
```

Once I run it the first time to initialize my tokens it works perfectly, but whenever I run it a second time I get a null pointer exception from token.getAthlete(), where the token is not null but all its attributes (including the Athelete attribute) are null.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what the lastToken.txt file contents are after the first time `main` is run?

Comment: Extending a non-serializable base class and making the derived class `Serializable` doesn't make the base class `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the project, the [Token class](https://github.com/danshannon/javastravav3api/blob/master/Strava%20API%20v3/src/javastrava/auth/model/Token.java) (as well as the athlete classes) does not implement Serializable.

You're extending `Token` via `SerialToken`, and `Token` isn't `Serializable` while its subclass is. What gives?

According to the [Serializable javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be
> initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
> class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
> serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored
> from the stream.

So basically, what happens when a class is serializable but its superclass is not ?

Well at the time of de-serialization, if a non-serializable superclass is present, then JVM will do nothing more with it than executing the default (no-arg) constructor of that class.

From the [Athlete class](https://github.com/danshannon/javastravav3api/blob/master/Strava%20API%20v3/src/javastrava/model/StravaAthlete.java) in the project, you'll notice `City` is a private String variable, and its default value will hence be `null`.

So when you deserialise it, you get back a null (since the no-arg constructor doesn't provide it a non-null value either). And then calling `getAthlete().getCity()` would hence result in `NullPointerException`.